# Apache Isis: create dialog with referenced object dropdown

Tags: isis

Given an Apache Isis project with a simple domain model such as below, what are the absolute minimum requirements for a create dialogue that will display a dropdown selection of all available Offices when creating a new Person?

Current state: I can create an office objects, list all office objects, but when I want to create a Person, the create dialogue doesn't show a dropdown of the available offices, it just says "(none)" (see screenshot).

Currently my create dialogue for Person looks like this:

[image: Person create dialog]

**How can I display a dropdown of all available offices in this dialogue?**

Here is a rough layout of the DOM code I have (JDO annotations omitted):

```
public class Office {
    private String name;
    // getter/setter ...
}

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Office office;
    // getter/setter...
}
```

and corresponding menu/repository classes such as

```
public class OfficeRepository {
    public List<Office> listAll() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PersonRepository {
    public Person create(String name, final Office office) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class PersonMenu {
    public static class CreateDomainEvent extends ActionDomainEvent<Person> {}    
    @Action(domainEvent = CreateDomainEvent.class)        
    public Person create(
        @ParameterLayout(named="Name")
        final String name,
        final Office office) {
        return personRepository.create(name, office);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the choices supporting method, the autoComplete supporting method, or annotate the referenced class as @DomainObject(bounded=true).  The latter is mostly appropriate for reference data objects with a limited (ie bounded) number of instances.

eg:

```
public List<Office> choices1Create()
    return officerRepository.findAll();
}
```

See these [apache isis docs](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun.html#_ugfun_how-tos_drop-downs-and-defaults) for (links to) further detali.

If you have other questions, I recommend you sign up to the apache.isis [mailing list](http://isis.apache.org/support.html#how-to-subscribe).

Thx
Dan

Comment: Thx Dan. I tried looking into the documentation earlier but exactly this part of the documentation is empty and only says "TODO".

Comment: re the docs... well, they are not quite empty, because they do have links to the relevant parts of the reference guides.  But I do admit that at first glance it would seem that there's no info there.

Re: the code snippet, have fixed (my bad).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Dan. On a side note: is there actually a reference of the isis metamodel constructed form the java code? I was reading through the [project ideas](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ISIS/ProjectIdeasForStudents) and it talks about the programming model, but I wasn't able to find any documentation on the metamodel itself. Just curious if you could point me somewhere, even a place in the code.

Comment: You would never have found this, but I did write up some stuff on this [README](https://github.com/alejandro-du/vaadin-viewer) for a viewer that one of the vaadin guys was going to do as his 10% project, but never found the time.